# isSalable() / isAvailable returning unexpected result for bundle product

Tags: magento-1.7, bundled-product

I've got a bundle product, which I'm loading as follows:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
if ($product->isSaleable()){
    echo "Is saleable!";
}
else{
    echo "Not saleable!";
}
```

P.S. isSalable() & isSaleable both refer to the same method.

I've double, tripple & quadruple checked and the product definitely is saleable. I've flushed every single cache & reindexed everything possible.

This method is **still** not returning the accurate result. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The method `isSaleable` calls the method `isAvailable` from the same class, that calls the method `isSalable` from the product type model.
In your case `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type::isSalable`.

most probably something in this one returns `false`. you can start debugging here.